# Tkinter button needs to be created multiple times in the same grid but doesn't, how do i get it to do that?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to add a button to the right of each row in a tkinter grid, below is my code, right now I've only been able to get it to print a button in the first row, what exactly am I doing wrong:

```
def search_function():
        search_term = '%' + error_search_bar.get() + '%'
        error_db_cursor.execute(sql_query, (str(search_term),))
        search_window = tk.Tk()
        search_window.geometry("561x800")
        search_window.title("ITBLUE | Search Results")
        further_button = tk.Button(search_window, text='More Info', width=19, height=4)
        for i, symptoms in enumerate(error_db_cursor): 
            for index, item in enumerate(symptoms):
                e = tk.Text(search_window, width=17, height=4) 
                e.grid(row=i, column=index)
                e.insert(END, item)
                further_button.grid(row=i, column=3)
```

Here is an image of how it looks right now:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOeQm.png)

**Update:** So I think I've figured out what's wrong, I can only load the same button once into the grid, so right now it consistently only puts the button in the last column, how would I work around this.

Comment: you shouldn't use `for j in range(len(symptoms)):`, instead use `for index, item in enumerate(symptoms)` index will return the current index and item the current item, then you can easily use `column=j` and `e.insert(END, item)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice, went and fixed that now, still getting the same result

Comment: Updated the code to match the fix @Matiis

Comment: you don't need this line then: `search_result = symptoms[index]` do you? and yes it won't fix the issue because I just showed how to write code more effectively. now, your issue is that `x` is reassigned each iteration, place `x = 1` right after `i = 0`

Comment: Thanks @Matiis, really appreciate the help man, only spotted that I iterated twice where I only needed to once, fixed that as well, I'm still pretty new to writing code

Comment: also you could simply use `for i, symptoms in enumerate(error_db_cursor):` that way you don't have to externally keep track of `i` and also `i = i + 1` can be reduced to `i += 1`

Comment: Awesome, that actually cut down my code by quite a bit already, it's looking so much better thanks @matiis

Comment: btw in the current code this line: `i+=1` can be removed, the loop already increases `i`, I was just telling you that that is a way of increasing a variable in a shorter manner